# CSV or JSON format

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, openpyxl

```
 import base64
import requests

USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'notworking', 'notworking'

def send_request():
    # Request

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/cumulative_player_stats.{format}", 
            params={
                "fordate": "20171009"
            },
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Basic " +
                     base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                      .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
            }
        )
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
            content=response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')
```

That code allows me to pull data from mysportsfeeds.com. Eventually, I will need to take the output of `send_request` function and format it in a `.xlsx` file with [`openpyxl`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlGq6R4U2gE) library. I don't know which format will be the most easier to treat, i.e. the output with `csv` or with `json` format.

That excellent [website](https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/data-feeds/api-docs#) will show you how to get the output of `cumulate_player_stats`.

For instance,

```
https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2016-2017-regular/cumulative_player_stats.{format}
```

where `{format}` is either `csv` or `json`

**Questions :**

What is the better choice : the output in `csv` format ou `json` format so that it will work well with `openpyxl` lib? Will anyone be able to show me how it could work with `csv` (with `csv` library) and `json` (with `json` library) in using `openpyxl`?

Comment: What format to use will come down to personal preference. You should break it down into stages, so instead of thinking whether csv or json will work better with openpyxl, work backwards... Figure out what format you need it in to output openpyxl (such as a list, or dictionary, etc.), then you can use json or csv and get it into that format. Personally I find csv easier but it depends on the data.

Comment: Requesting the data as CSV will allow you to seamlessly dump your data into an Excel format.

Comment: JSON is a standard with no extrinsic formatting parameters. CSV is an example of "The great thing about standards, is that there are so many to choose from." Also, it requires the writer to communicate to the reader, the character encoding, the line separator, the field separator, the text qualifier, the text qualifier escape mechanism, whether there is a header row, and what the types of each column are. Some programs are good a guessing such things but often with on the spot guidance from a human.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a row-based file format. This would suggest CSV, which is row based. But CSV files are text-only, meaning that they contain no type information and you have to guess whether "9/10/17" means the 9th of October (20)17, the 10th of September (20)17, simply "9/10/17".

JSON is at least types but will need to be read into memory all at once. Assuming that it merely a list of list then it would probably be the best option here because Excel worksheets cannot have more than a million rows.